# Are questions about Coffee Bean Oil on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Are question about uses of pure coffee oil on topic?

The essential oil is processed through the process of cold pressing using the beans and is a dark brown colour in appearance.

Answer (score 6):

The beta at Area 51 is defined as follows:

> Beta Q&A site for people interested in all aspects of producing and consuming coffee.

Seems that pure coffee oil would fit that bill. I have no experience with coffee oil and I am guessing that is true of many other people, so a few well structured question and answers would be informative.